# Potential leak of an object when using SecCertificateCopyData

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, memory-management

The analyzer says that a potential leak is there.
Please look at the attached screenshot, I don't think there is an issue here but just want to be sure. Enviornment- ARC[image]

You can open the image in a new tab if it is too small to view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there a leak. You should use:

```
NSData *serverCertificateData = (__bridge_transfer NSData*)SecSecurityCopyData(...);
```

so that ARC takes responsibility for releasing the data.